# What do percentage signs (%) mean in HTML?

Tags: html, conditional-statements

Here is the code I am trying to decipher. It seems like the percentage sign allows conditional logic?

```
<div class="result" align="center">
    {% if result %}
        {% for variable, value in original_input.items() %}
            <b>{{ variable }}</b> : {{ value }}
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
        <br> Predicted number of bikes in use:
        <p style="font-size:50px">{{ result }}</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: That's not HTML. That's for JavaScript or another scripting language to replace data.

Comment: https://octobercms.com/docs/markup/tag-if

Comment: It's not PHP, @DhruviMakvana. It may be some templating language which is *implemented* in PHP, such as Twig.

Answer (score 4):

In HTML? Nothing. That's some templating language. Twig uses `{% %}` to surround logical operators, and `{{ }}` to surround output, but so do a fair few other templating languages for HTML.

This should be parsed server-side by some templating engine, and the result (which will be actual HTML) served to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

There are many frameworks that use templates or with server side rendering or with client side rendering that can be an additional layer to JavaScript or HTML or CSS.

This framework that you are writing at is a PHP framework, probably [October CMS](https://octobercms.com/) as @sergey commented.

In pure HTML `{%` means nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not HTML code.

This is **Django template language**. More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/) to explain how this is turned into actual HTML once served.

Comment: You are very correct but the exact syntax differs between languages. The use of these specific template tags given in the question appear to be Django. Other languages might use the exact same syntax though.